# Creating a planet out of an existing terrain

Tags: unity, c#

I am creating a game that I have created a terrain for. I really like the terrain so I am wanting to keep it but I want to have the game take place on a full planet. Avoiding paying $200 for an asset already made, how would I develop something to allow me to "tile" this terrain to make a full planet and to make it round instead of flat? I know this has to be somewhat possible with the expensive assets on the asset store that are for round terrains. I just need to figure out how and I can't find anything online that is much help.

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is "treadmill terrain". I haven't used this particular one, but it's only $5: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9923

Comment: @DavidLively Ah interesting. I will have to look into this. I appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Note that this is applicable if you're on or close to the surface. If you're, say, in orbit, or high enough that you can see the curvature of the planet, things get more... interesting.

Comment: @DavidLively Yeah I thought of that. But in my game there won't be any getting off of the planet to see that so no big deal!

Comment: @DavidLively My only real issue is getting the terrains to match up right and also making sure that only one of the tiles of terrain has specific gameobjects in them like certain buildings.

Comment: @DavidLively, I ran into the curvature issue before, since mapping to sphere coordinates can get messy, with corners of squares wrapping further than the rest of the perimeter. It sounds like it likely won't be needed for this specific project, but for those looking for curvature, the $10 Sphere Distort utility might help: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8305

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Unity provides any default component or tool to create spherical terrains. You can create a world and a mesh procedurally, needs some coding. You can either change the transform of gameobjects to another point when you collide with them, which you can write inside OnTriggerEnter().

In your case, you could do a little hardwork and make the spherical terrain using a 3D application like Blender. Best of luck :)